# Проблема с PDO и ООП

Tags: ооп, php_pdo, классы, php

Функция select() ничего не выводит. На страницу лезет следующее:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Код страницы с классом, который подключаю:

```
// Класс для работы с БД

class DB {
    //Параметры для подключения
    protected $hostname = "localhost";
    protected $password = "bek7b7";
    protected $user = "home";
    protected $name = "project";

    public function connect() { //Подключаемся...
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->hostname.'; dbname='.$this->name, $this->user, $this->password); 
            $db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function select($table, $where){ // Получаем данные из БД
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM :table WHERE :where');    
        $sth->bindParam(':table', $table);
        $sth->bindParam(':where', $where);
        $sth->execute();

        return '=P';  
    }
}
```

Код основной страницы:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            require_once 'classes/DB.class.php';
            $db = new DB();
            $db->connect();
            echo $db->select('us', 'pass = bek7b7');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

После долгих раздумий изменил "$db" на "$this->db",но сервер начал кричать

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object
> на строке 
> $this->db->query('SET NAMES utf8');

Если эту строку закомментировать, то он начнёт орать на строки с prepare.

Comment: Судя по ошибке объект не был создан, сделайте var_dump для $this->db и полный код ошибки, плиз.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но зачем вы вообще шлете query с установкой utf8?

Читайте документацию по конструктору перед тем как писать такое.

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb', 'login', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));

И если я не ошибаюсь у вас неймспейсы используются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class DB {
    //Параметры для подключения
    protected $hostname = "localhost";
    protected $password = "bek7b7";
    protected $user = "home";
    protected $name = "project";
    private $db;

    public function connect() { //Подключаемся...
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->hostname.'; dbname='.$this->name, $this->user, $this->password); 
            $this->query('SET NAMES utf8');
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function select($table, $where){ // Получаем данные из БД
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM :table WHERE :where');    
        $sth->bindParam(':table', $table);
        $sth->bindParam(':where', $where);
        $sth->execute();

        return '=P';  
    }
}
```

Вы пропустили ключевое слово `this` для работы с переменными внутри класса.

Comment: @Витя Антишов  Также у вас неправильно происходит привязка параметра запроса к переменной, а именно :where

Comment: что с параметром не так, если не секрет?)
То, что он не работает, я знаю, но пока что отложил эту проблему

Comment: @Витя Антишов бинд происходит по другому:

 $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE param = :value');    
 $sth->bindParam(':value', $value);

Т.е. мы можем забиндить только значение параметра `param`, но никак не целое выражение.

Также нельзя биндить имена таблиц, т.к. это не значение какого-либо параметра.

Comment: В этом то вся и проблема. Хочу привести всё к полнейшей унификации.